# Cannot locate ChangeText class/symbol

Tags: android

I am trying to add some animation in my Android app for a text change on a TextView.
I found a post with sample:
[Smooth text change in android animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715142/smooth-text-change-in-android-animation)

Sample code:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer,
        new ChangeText().setChangeBehavior(ChangeText.CHANGE_BEHAVIOR_OUT_IN));
```

I have imported the following package:

```
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;
```

However, when I use this, I get an error in Android Studio: *****Cannot resolve symbol ChangeText*****

What am I missing? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original Answer mentions that a library is needed:

> If you want to support Android 4+. check out the [Transitions Everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) lib. You can achieve all sorts of different animations with backward compatibility.
> [Here](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50#.his5la68z) you can find some examples.

Therefore you might need to install the library via gradle and then import it like so:

```java
import com.transitionseverywhere.ChangeText;
```

or

```java
import com.transitionseverywhere.*;
```

Comment: Thank you Jakob, this is useful. I cannot vote up because I don't have adequate reputation.